# Weird result when retrieve date from Cassandra with python

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

I'm using `Cassandra` version 2.0.1 and python with `cql` 1.4 library.
This is the description of the table `instruments`:

```
CREATE TABLE instruments (
  key text,
  field text,
  valid_date timestamp,
  publication_date timestamp,
  insertion_date timestamp,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, field, valid_date, publication_date, insertion_date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (field ASC, valid_date DESC, publication_date DESC, insertion_date DESC) AND
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='NONE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

Using cqlsh with the query:

```
select key, field, valid_date, publication_date, insertion_date, value from instruments where key='instrument1' and field='currency' and valid_date <= 1376524800000;
```

I have the results

```
 key         | field    | valid_date               | publication_date         | insertion_date           | value
-------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------
 instrument1 | currency | 2013-08-15 02:00:00+0200 | 2013-08-15 02:00:00+0200 | 2013-08-15 02:00:00+0200 |   USD
```

But when using cql in a python program, I got:

```
list: [u'instrument1', u'currency', '\x00\x00\x01@\x7fE\x90\x00', '\x00\x00\x01@\x7fE\x90\x00', '\x00\x00\x01@\x7fE\x90\x00', u'USD']
```

How can I properly retrieve the result from the database? This problem occurs when I upgrade casssandra server to 2.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bugged timestamps on cqlengine (Cassandra 2.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968607/bugged-timestamps-on-cqlengine-cassandra-2-0)

Comment: Yes I think this is the same problem. But there is not good solution yet, for the moment I must go back to previous version of Cassandra in order to continue the project, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the datastax python driver?

Comment: No but as they said it's not recommended for production at the moment, I prefer to switch back to prevous version